Ubuntu Server 24.04 has no internet while installing
i decided to reuse my old pc and use it as an Home Server.
I installed Ubuntu Server version 24.04 via an USB stick. Everything was fine till i came across the network configuartion (The PC is connected via an Ethernet cabel) where i end in an endless searching for an connection. I know that the ethernet cabel and all works on the PC because befor I installed Ubuntu there was Windows installed and that had an internet connection. Even after the installtion of Ubuntu I can´t seem to get an connection. I tryd varios reconfiguration of netplan but nothing seems to work.
Edit:
Here are the images from the command output sudo lspci -v
First Output Image
Second
Third
Fourth

Check the cable connection maybe the cable got loose? Run Ubuntu Server live and see if you still have the problem. Then you can try debugging it : https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-troubleshoot-an-ethernet-interface-ubuntu-server-with-ethtool/

Nothing seems to work even your suggention. I even tryed diffrent distros. But it looks like its not the software or my Ethernat cabel. I noticed that ubuntu uses the forcedeth ethernet driver, wierd question but do i need my graphic card installed for this? I am just going crazy at this point!

My machine seems to work to...

No, graphics card will not affect it. Did you start from a live CD / usb drive? It could be a drivers issue with the network card. Run  sudo lspci -v  and post the results.

I installed it via a USB, i added the images of the output.

I did some further testing. I installed Windows 10 again and there the Ethernet works without a problem. So i think Ubuntu has some kind of driver issue. A little note i also installed Kali Linux and there was the same ethernet problem.
